# How do I remove /public from the URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim-3

I am using Slim framework to build a website. How to I re-write the url using .htaccess ?

This is what my .htaccess file looks like, any route is redirected to index page, I got this from the [Slim Documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This is my directory structure.

```
|--app
|--bootstrap
|--public
   |--css
   |--js
   |--index.php
   |--.htaccess
|--routes
|--vendor
|--views
|--composer.json
|--composer.lock
```

This how it works now

http://localhost/SlimApplication/public/ - points to the index page
http://localhost/SlimApplication/public/Users - points to the users page

This is how I want it to work

http://localhost/SlimApplication/ - should point to the index page
http://localhost/SlimApplication/Users - should point to the users page

What can I do to make this work ?? I am new at .htaccess and Slim as well so any help would be great. Thanks, Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Create new .htaccess file in level up folder hierarchy (the same as public folder). RewriteBase /public/ directive is what you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I tried this out but it doesn't seem to work even more it breaks the how the links were working before.